# regex for accepting spaces only between words

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regular expression where the user should enter just a word or words with space between them and its length must have a limit [1 to 32].

For instance, it should accept below line;

```
wordX[space]wordX[space][space][space]wordX
```

but it should not accept that:

`[space]wordX` or `wordX[space]` or only `[space]`

wordX must be compatible with this regex:

```
^(([0-9A-Za-z!"#$%'()*+,./:;=?@^_`{|}~\\\[\]-]))$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?:\w+\s){0,31}\w+$
```

`\w` means: digits, letters, underscore

For strictly accepted chars:

```
^(?:[\w!"#$%'()*+,./:;=?@^_`{|}~\\\[\]]+\s){0,31}[\w!"#$%'()*+,./:;=?@^_`{|}~\\\[\]]+$
```

Or:

```
^(?:\S+\s){0,31}\S+$
```

`\S` - any character other than whitespace

**Update**:

If word length is between 1 and 32 than use this regex:

```
^(?:\w{1,31}\s)*\w{1,31}$
```

In the same manner you can modify other regexes.

Comment: thanks but limit is not working. I tested on this page:
http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary

Comment: just anything more than 32 characters. it accepts any word without limit.

Comment: @onuR, Is it word length limit or words count limit?

Comment: thanks a lot. I have one more issue, how can check  total length of the phrase not only a word?

Comment: @onuR, Try this `^(?=.{40,100}$)(?:\w{1,31}\s)*\w{1,31}$` From 40 to 100 chars. I don't know, does your regex engine support lookahead...